# sqlite3 C API doesn't release memory on sqlite3_close

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite

I have a server application which stores all the connections in some pool. After loosing it's connection to another app my app destructs all the objects expect for network connection objects. So all the objects are destructed successfully and db connections pool is destructed also but the memory is not released.

Connections in the pool are stored like:

```
std::unordered_map<int, DbConnection> connections;
```

Destruction of sqlite db connection is like:

```
if (sqlite3_close(sqliteDB) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    printf(errormsg);
}
```

The problem is sqlite3_close always returns SQLITE_OK in this case. So it's supposed to release the memory but it doesn't do it. And after every reconnect the amount of memory consumed by my app increases almost twice! It is definitely the memory of sqlite is not released, not something else. But when I run my app with massif (valgrind tool) everything works fine and there no memory leaks at all. So I can't understand how to solve this problem. I'm using fedora 19, but it's possible to trigger this error on every linux distributive.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: It is not guaranteed the OS will immediately take back the memory you free. In fact, I believe most of the times it will not. How exactly are you measuring memory usage?

Comment: htop or top on linux. The amount of memory used for db connections pool I measured via valgrind-massif.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the memory fragmentation, that's why OS doesn't release it immediately. [malloc_trim(0)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html) can help to solve this problem but then appears the problem of completely fragmented memory. But it's another topic.